# Determining the cell from a UILongPressRecognizer for a segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm having a slight problem with a basic checklist app I'm building.

On a regular tap of a table view cell, I segue to my `NewTaskViewController` using `prepare(for segue)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddTask" {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let newTaskVc = nav.topViewController as! NewTaskViewController
        newTaskVc.delegate = self
        newTaskVc.managedContext = managedContext
```

I also have perform a segue on a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` that I added to my cell. Long pressing should segue to the same `NewTaskViewController` but this time adding the cell's `TaskItem` to its `taskToEdit` property

```
    } else if segue.identifier == "EditTask" {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let editTaskVc = nav.topViewController as! NewTaskViewController
        editTaskVc.delegate = self
        editTaskVc.managedContext = managedContext
        editTaskVc.taskToEdit = ?
```

As I'm using a `UILongPressRecognizer`, I'm struggling to work out how I determine the index path of the cell long-pressed so I can pass the correct item through.

Essentially, how do I identify a table view cell from a gesture recognizer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well could you try something like this inside your handling function?

```
if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
    let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchPoint) {
        // Your Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! What I did here was store the indexPath in a stored property in the class and accessed it in `prepareForSegue`!